# Displaying message in JSF application

Tags: javascript, jsf, onmouseover

How is it possible to display a simple message in a JSF application when the mouse moves over a specific element of the interface? I have tried this code, but it didn't work, no message is displayed:

JSF file:

```
<h:form id ="f">
<h:selectManyCheckbox onmouseover="#{hello.message()}" layout="pageDirection" border="1"  value="#{hello.customersSelect}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{hello.customers}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectManyCheckbox><br />
<h:commandButton action="response.xhtml" value="Click me" />
</h:form>
```

The backing bean Hello (ManagedBean) contains the method message() as:

```
public void message(){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("f", new FacesMessage("Done"));
}
```

I suppose I should add somewhere a tag h:message, but I couldn't get it done, despite my efforts. Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `title` attribute containing your message as a String?

Comment: `onmouseover` is a JavaScript function and you're passing a server side method. Change it for a JavaScript function that handles your message presentation (an `alert` or something else).

Comment: @f_puras have you read OP's code?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, it won't work. I supposed he just wants a tooltip for the checkboxes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I want necessarily to pass the server side method. How can this be done in JSF? That is my question. I am not interested in implementing it in Javascript.

Comment: Answer posted, but IMO this looks like a bad option/solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Let's have a simple one.

Comment: @f_puras I mean, what real world purpose would have to send a server request (via ajax or not) when setting the mouse over a dropdownlist? This really looks like bad design, maybe the real solution would be firing the request in the `onchange` event.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well, as you said in your answer: We do not know what exactly the OP wants to achieve, so we can only guess by proposing answers. Ajax for a mouseover does look extreme, so I tried a minimal static approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satisfy your curiosity, use `<f:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{hello.messageListener}" />`:

JSF code

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" border="1"
    value="#{hello.customersSelect}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{hello.customers}"></f:selectItems>

    <f:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{hello.messageListener}" render="messages" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
<br />
<h:messages id="messages" />
```

Hello bean code

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Hello {
    //attributes, constructor and other methods

    public void messageListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) { 
        System.out.println("OnMouseOver ajax event.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null, new FacesMessage("Done"));
    }
}
```

But more importantly, are you sure this is the solution to your real problem? It would be better to specify the functional requirement in order to get better help.

Answer (score 1):

you should handle it in javascript as mouseOver is a dom event

```
<h:head>    
<h:outputScript library="js" name="rollover.js" />
[...]
<h:form id ="f">
<h:selectManyCheckbox onmouseover="mouseOn('foobar')" layout="pageDirection" border="1"  value="#{hello.customersSelect}">
```

and the rollover.js :

```
function mouseOn(text) {
   alert(text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a static message being shown, which does not change while the page is displayed:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectManyCheckbox title="#{hello.message}" layout="pageDirection"
        border="1" value="#{hello.customersSelect}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{hello.customers}"></f:selectItems>
    </h:selectManyCheckbox><br />
    <h:commandButton action="response.xhtml" value="Click me" />
</h:form>
```

And the bean:

```
public String getMessage() {
    return "Done";
}
```

No JavaScript at all ;-)